# Access: passing value to a parameter query using VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013

I have a an Access form with a parameter query (pink color). Here is my form:

[image]

When the user selects a species, Access uses the number generated by the option group (called "speciesSelection") to lookup the species name in a table, and it works. However, I would like to pass the species name to a parameter query, so that a record set can be the data source for the highlighted combo box (Combo12). However, when I select a species, the combo box is blank. Here is my code:

```vb
Private Sub speciesSelection_AfterUpdate()
Dim dbs As Database
Dim qdf As QueryDef
Dim rst As Recordset

Set dbs = CurrentDb

'Get species name of the current Cases instance'
Dim speciesChosen As String
speciesChosen = DLookup("Species", "tblSpeciesList", "ID=" & speciesSelection)

'Get the parameter query
Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs("qryClinicalObservations")

'Supply the parameter value
qdf.Parameters("enterSpecies") = speciesChosen

'Open a Recordset based on the parameter query
Forms!inputForm.Controls!Combo12.RowSource = qdf.OpenRecordset()
End Sub
```

I created my query using the wizard. Here is a snapshot:

[image]

In the criteria section, I can manually enter a species when prompted (e.g. "cat"), and it works. But not with my VBA code...

Is there an obvious mistake? It seems that Combo12 is not recognized.

EDIT:

Here is my new code. Actually, Combo12 is in a subform called observationsSubform. Here is my code and new form. As you can see, the drop-down menu, but the options aren't visible:

```
Private Sub speciesSelection_AfterUpdate()
Dim dbs As Database
Dim qdf As QueryDef
Dim rst As Recordset

Set dbs = CurrentDb

'Get species name of the current Cases instance'
Dim speciesChosen As String
speciesChosen = DLookup("Species", "tblSpeciesList", "ID=" & speciesSelection)

MsgBox (speciesChosen)

'Get the parameter query
Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs("qryClinicalObservations")

'Supply the parameter value
qdf!enterSpecies = speciesChosen

Set Me!observationsSubform!Combo12.Recordset = qdf.OpenRecordset()
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like your combobox has 2 columns, the first one invisible, but your query returns only one column, so the visible combobox column is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combo box's `RowSource` is a string property, so you can't assign a `Recordset` object to it.  Assign your `Recordset` to the combo's `Recordset` property instead.

Since that is an object assignment, use the `Set` keyword.

```vb
Set Forms!inputForm!Combo12.Recordset = qdf.OpenRecordset()
```

If `Combo12` and `speciesSelection` are both contained in the same form (`inputForm`), you can use this instead ...

```vb
Set Me!Combo12.Recordset = qdf.OpenRecordset()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I just realized that Combo 12 is in a subform called observationsSubform. Combo12 is now recognized, the drop-down menu works, but I can't see any entries. So, I'm almost there? Could you please look at the edit? Thank you! :)

Comment: Have you checked whether `qdf.OpenRecordset()` returned any rows?

Comment: Actually, it worked great, it was simply a column editing problem! :) Now, it works perfectly! Thank you very much again!